# SQL Query optimization for delete query

Tags: sql-server, optimization, ssms

I am trying to optimize the query below so I indexed its primary key

```
DELETE from LSS_FPAVServiceXml 
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, LEFT(trackingid, 8)) < CAST(CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE() - 90, 101) AS SMALLDATETIME)
```

Index code for `trackingid` is:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[LSS_FPAVServiceXml] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_LSS_FPAVRequest] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([trackingid] ASC)
```

And after that in execution plan cost: 73%. Is there any other way I can optimize this query?

Please suggest!

Comment: Basically when you calculate over column query optimizer cannot use index on it and have to do full scan.

Comment: Indexes are irrelevant because you are wrapping the column with functions. Can you provide the data type of trackingid and provide sample data?

Comment: if indexes are irrelevant with the function , it means i cant more optimized it . is it corrent?

Comment: It can be optimized, but not with indexes (at least not as it is currently designed)

Comment: whats the original datatype of `trackingid`and what are you doing to that poor innocent `getdate`?

Comment: ohh ok.. could you please suggest any other way .Thanks

Comment: Provide sample data and I can

Comment: trackingid is PK,Varchar(20), not null variable. Here is some BL to delete some id (which is the combination of date and other serial number ) before 90 days.

Comment: 2015061000001,2015061000002,2015061000003,2015061000004

Comment: @sony921 Give my answer a try and let me know how it goes :)

Comment: @ghost Sure.. i am on it :-)

Comment: @ghost  thats work great  :-)  optimization cost was 824 and now its 67.84. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are the unfortunate owner of a database where multiple values are stored in a single field, you have three options.

1. Fix the design. Storing multiple values in a single column is a no-no. Store the values in single columns and in the proper data-types. Index those columns and you'll get fast performance generally.
2. Can't fix the design because it'll be too costly/risky? Create columns that are computed from the original column. Index those computed columns and you'll get fast performance generally.
3. If you've gotten to this point, it's likely you are in deep trouble. Without columns that can be indexed, you have to wrap all references in functions to get your values for your query's joins/where; this will result in table scans and poor performance. If you are ***lucky***, the data is formatted in such a way you can order it alphabetically.

You are lucky in this case. Based on the sample data, you should be able to do this:

```
DELETE from LSS_FPAVServiceXml 
where trackingid LIKE CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEADD(DAY,-90,GETDATE()),112) + '%'
```